# parse dicomdir to display available images

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

We are thinking to add **image management** function by parse the existing **dicomdir** file and display the content with a **tree structure**. The existing application is using **Java** with **Dcm4Che**.

My qestion is how to **parse the dicomdir file** to get enough information to display its content in **Java tree**?

Comment: From my experience i can tell you that is better to scan the all the folders and build your own tree. In the dicomdir you will find only directory information (the reason is called dir) and sooner or later you will end up with parsing the folder structure (maybe for displaying the resolution of the image in the tree). If it helps i can give you some C++ code for parsing the dicomdir.

Comment: I agree w/ alinoz. It's easy enough to recurse through the directory tree and read a bit of each DICOM file to put together this tree-like structure.

Answer (score 0):

More Refer here :: [DICOMDIR READ IMAGES](http://jaypthakkar.blogspot.in/search?q=DICOMDIR)

```
public void getFilePath(DicomObject firstRecord) throws IOException { 
  int i = 1; 
    for (DicomObject rec = firstRecord; rec != null; rec = dicomDir 
      .findNextSiblingRecord(rec), ++i) {
         if (rec.get(Tag.ReferencedFileID) != null) {
               File f = dicomDir.toReferencedFile(rec);
              System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
              }
         getFilePath(dicomDir.findFirstChildRecord(rec));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here for Same Code](http://jaypthakkar.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-read-dicom-directory-dicomdir-in.html)

```
private DicomDirReader dirReader;

public ReadDicomDir(File file) throws IOException {
    dirReader = new DicomDirReader(file);
}

public List<File> getFiles() throws IOException {
    List<File> listDirFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    getFilePath(dirReader.findFirstRootRecord(), listDirFiles);
    return listDirFiles;
}

/**
 * Get Filepath of Dicom File
 * 
 * @param firstRecord
 * @param listDirFiles
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void getFilePath(DicomObject firstRecord, List<File> listDirFiles)
        throws IOException {
    int i = 1;
    for (DicomObject rec = firstRecord; rec != null; rec = dirReader
            .findNextSiblingRecord(rec), ++i) {
        if (rec.contains(Tag.ReferencedFileID)) {
            File f = dirReader.toReferencedFile(rec);
            // System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            listDirFiles.add(f);
        }
        getFilePath(dirReader.findFirstChildRecord(rec), listDirFiles);
    }
```